# Calculating min difference between two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, min

I'm trying to calculate difference between two dictionaries to return a specific value.

I've entered different values which should return different results, but the result remains unchanged.

```
diets = {"normal" : {'p': '32.50', 'c': '60', 'f': '40.86'},
         "oncology" : {'p': '35', 'c': '52.50', 'f': '37.63'},
         "cardiology" : {'p': '32.50', 'c': '30', 'f': '26.88'},
         "diabetes" : {'p': '20', 'c': '27.50', 'f': '27.95'},
         "kidney" : {'p': '15', 'c': '55', 'f': '23.65'}}

amounts = {'p': p, 'c': c, 'f': f}

value = { k : diets[k] for k in set(diets) - set(amounts) }

calculate_error = min(value)

print(calculate_error)
```

When i input 32, 60 and 40, the returned result should be normal, but oncology is returned instead

Comment: What's `p`, `c` and `f` values in your `amounts` dictionary?

Comment: p = 32, c = 60 and f = 40. What should happen is regardless of what numbers are entered the smallest absolute difference should be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the values you are creating when you do this:

```
set(diets)
```

This is just a list of keys.

```
{'cardiology', 'diabetes', 'kidney', 'normal', 'oncology'}
```

When you subtract the other list of keys, you just get the original list because no values are in common.

You need to actually step through the items and do the subtraction to get the differences. Then you can find the sum of the diffs and the min of that sum.

One way would be:

```
diets = {"normal" : {'p': '32.50', 'c': '60', 'f': '40.86'},
         "oncology" : {'p': '35', 'c': '52.50', 'f': '37.63'},
         "cardiology" : {'p': '32.50', 'c': '30', 'f': '26.88'},
         "diabetes" : {'p': '20', 'c': '27.50', 'f': '27.95'},
         "kidney" : {'p': '15', 'c': '55', 'f': '23.65'}}
amounts = {'p': 32., 'c': 60., 'f': 40.}

mins = [(diet, sum([abs(amounts[k] - float(d[k])) for k in amounts])) for diet, d in diets.items()]
the_min = min(mins, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

`mins` will be:

```
[('normal', 1.3599999999999994),
 ('oncology', 12.869999999999997),
 ('cardiology', 43.620000000000005),
 ('diabetes', 56.55),
 ('kidney', 38.35)]
```

`the_min` will be:

```
('normal', 1.3599999999999994)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. But I'd like to print the_min without the digits, just the text.

Comment: @JordanGamson `the_min` is just a tuple. To print just the text: `print(the_min[0])`. You need numbers in the mins because that's what `min` uses to find the minimum, but you don't need to use or keep them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you totally confused what `value` would be

```
>>> diets = {"normal" : {'p':'32.50', 'c':'60', 'f':'40.86'},
...          "oncology" : {'p':'35', 'c':'52.50', 'f':'37.63'},
...          "cardiology" : {'p':'32.50', 'c':'30', 'f':'26.88'},
...          "diabetes" : {'p':'20', 'c':'27.50', 'f':'27.95'},
...          "kidney" : {'p':'15', 'c':'55', 'f':'23.65'}}
>>> set(diets)
{'kidney', 'cardiology', 'oncology', 'normal', 'diabetes'}
>>> amounts = {'p':32, 'c':60, 'f':40}
>>> set(amounts)
{'c', 'f', 'p'}
>>> set(diets) - set(amounts)
{'cardiology', 'diabetes', 'kidney', 'oncology', 'normal'}
>>> value = { k : diets[k] for k in set(diets) - set(amounts) }
>>> value
{'cardiology': {'p': '32.50', 'c': '30', 'f': '26.88'},
 'diabetes': {'p': '20', 'c': '27.50', 'f': '27.95'},
 'kidney': {'p': '15', 'c': '55', 'f': '23.65'},
 'oncology': {'p': '35', 'c': '52.50', 'f': '37.63'},
 'normal': {'p': '32.50', 'c': '60', 'f': '40.86'}}
>>> min(value)
'cardiology'
```

that said I would expect that you to get `cardiology`, i.e. the min from `diets.keys()`
That said, note that the values in the diets are str, e.g. '32.50', You will need to convert these before any calculations.